# How to manipulate column values when using gnuplot from a shell script?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot from a bash script and I have to divide values from two columns:

plot "results.csv" using 1:($4/$6) notitle with lp

This works fine in gnuplot interactive mode, but when called from a script, the column values get mixed up with bash script arguments...How can I pass the col. values from the script?

Comment: How do you call gnuplot from your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on how exactly you're invoking gnuplot from your script, as Sean asked in the comments.

Something like `$4` will be expanded unless it's in single quotes, so that's one option. Anywhere else, you'll have to escape the `$`:

```
# print first argument
echo $1

# print literally $1, a few ways
echo '$1'
echo "\$1"
echo \$1
```

Comment: Thanks Jefromi, escaping with \ worked! Escaping with "$1" produces some strange values. You really helped me a lot with your quick answer :)

Comment: @ana: That was a typo in the example. In the text I said only single quotes will protect it from parameter expansion; double quotes do not, so you must escape it with a backslash there too.